# Error in integrating Google Map API to iOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, ios7, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using the google map API for my iOS Application. Till yesterday it was working very fine but today the map is not loading and I am continuous getting the following errors :

```
ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x7f8b151ce8f0 
{data=<CFData 0x7f8b106eafd0 [0x10bf309a0]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
```

I have checked the bundle ID of my app at google console and it is same as it is in my application.

The Google API keys and browser keys are also same.

So, I am currently unable to find out what the error is. Any help or suggestion will be great.

Comment: are you using the latest sdk of google map (version 1.9.2) ?

Comment: I am using GoogleMaps-iOS-1.9.1

Comment: im not sure this will fix ur problem. But u can try with the new sdk

Comment: It was working well till yesterday. But today I am getting this error. So I don't think it is a SDK issue.

Comment: are u testing in the real device or in simulator ?  if ur testing in simulator make sure u have turned on the location service of the simulator.( Debug -> Location )

Comment: I am testing on simulator and custom location service is on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76329/discussion-between-sannny-and-sarath-ios).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution, not a good one but it worked. I went to google console and created a new app for my bundle ID and then it worked perfectly. I still don't know what was the exact issue with previous scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Cause of issue :

Cause 1: May be bundle id of google console and your application is not matching .(application bundle id and google console bundle id should be same).

Solution : Steps a: GoTo google console and login with your application google account .

for finding key :: open google console > select your project > API & Auth > Credential

b: change bundle id and regenerate key .

c: replace previous key with your new generated key . [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];

Cause 2: May be key is not matching with you google console key .

Solution: Just replace your application key with google console key . [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];

Note: Make sure your application bundle id and google console bundle id is same .

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"XXXXXX"];
```

instead of:

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"{XXXXXX}"];
```